# xslt separators with 'and' before the last item

Tags: xml, xpath, foreach, xslt-1.0, separator

I have a problem here being that I have to display the courseName awards separated by commas for a cover letter. that is fine I can do that using a for-each code with a , separator. the problem Is I would like to insert and 'and' string before the last award. and I have no way on how to go one with it. any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
  I wish to apply for the above post. i have
```

---

this here being the xml code

---

```
<!-- educational history starts below-->
<school>    
    <education>     
        <fromYear> 2010 </fromYear>
        <toYear> 2014 </toYear>
        <courseName> Bachelor of Science in Physocology </courseName>
        <institution> The University of Dublin, Trinity College </institution>

    </education>

    <education>
        <fromYear> 2004 </fromYear>
        <toYear> 2010 </toYear>
        <institution> Cadbury College, Ballyknock, CoRoscommon </institution>
            <subject>English (A1),Irish (B2) , History (B2),French (B3)and Maths (B1)</subject>
    </education>
    <education>
        <institution> University of Dublin, Trinity College </institution>
        <courseName>Bachelor of Arts in Economics, June 2005 </courseName>
        <subjects> Firms and Development, Statistics, Applied Economics and International Economics </subjects>
    </education>
</school>
```

Comment: Have you already set up an XSLT stylesheet? -- if yes, please post it. Can you post the expected ouput as well?

Answer (score 0):

So:

- Before position=1, insert nothing
- Before position=2..last()-1, insert ","
- Before position=last(), insert ", and "

That's

```
<xsl:for-each select=".....">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="position()=1"/>
   <xsl:when test="position()=last()">, and </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>, </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```